# Python: year or month on x axis with pyplot, pandas and matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, axis

There are plethora of different solutions, mostly outdated, to address the addition of axis in matplotlib object, haven't got any of them working yet. I want to get date labels (either Months or Years) on the x axis.

### **How to add the date annotations on the axis in Python with Pandas and Matplotlib?**

**MWE**

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import savefig

a=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
a.pivot(index='date', columns='group').plot()
savefig("plot3.png")
```

**test.csv**

```
date,group,myval
2018-07-01,test1,999
2018-07-01,test2,523
2018-07-02,test1,3305
2018-07-02,test2,1290
2018-07-03,test1,9399
2018-07-03,test2,1827
2018-07-04,test1,6982
2018-07-04,test2,2391
2018-07-05,test1,4100
2018-07-05,test2,2081
2018-07-06,test1,0268
2018-07-06,test2,4834
2018-07-07,test1,9571
2018-07-07,test2,6369
2018-07-08,test1,3943
2018-07-08,test2,6483
```

[image]

where the time annotations are missing.

Comment: Convert colum `date` to `datetime` by `a=pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Comments have the following solutions, solutions tested to work.*

**I. Convert date column to datetime dtype `a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'])` and plot.**

```
a=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date']) 
a.pivot(index='date', columns='group').plot()
```

where adjust the formatting as needed such as

```
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

[image]

**II. Convert colum date to datetime by `a = pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=[0])`**

```
a=pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=[0]) 
a.pivot(index='date', columns='group').plot()
```